# Showing Anonymous user error and also not able to check whether user is authenticated only on one page.Working fine on all others in django

Tags: python, django

My views.py was working fine for every function except the below one(handlerequest).It is showing me error that Anonymous user has no object customer on website even when there is (working correctly on other pages).

This is my views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def handlerequest(request):
    customer=request.user.customer
    order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
    form = request.POST
    response_dict = {}
    for i in form.keys():
        response_dict[i] = form[i]
        if i == 'CHECKSUMHASH':
            checksum = form[i]

    verify = Checksum.verify_checksum(response_dict, MERCHANT_KEY, checksum)
    if verify:
        if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
            
            print('order successful')
        else:
            print('order was not successful because' + response_dict['RESPMSG'])
    return render(request, 'paymentstatus.html', {'response': response_dict,'types':Category.objects.all()})
```

Also in my html which I have given below even after writing the if else conditions it is not showing whether the user is logged in or not and it is working correctly for all other pages but not the html page under this view.Below is my html which is working fine for all html files except paymentstatus.html(from the view above)

```
                                 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                    <li class="d-none d-xl-block">
                                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                            Hello , {{user.first_name}}
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="d-none d-xl-block"> <a href="/logout/" class="btn header-btn">Logout</a>
                                    </li>

                                    {% else %}
                                    <li class="d-none d-xl-block"> <a href="/signup/" class="btn header-btn">Sign Up</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="d-none d-xl-block"> <a href="/login/" class="btn header-btn">Login</a>
                                    </li>
                                    {% endif %}
```

Please help me with this.

This is the error I am getting:AttributeError: `'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'customer'`

Comment: can you please update your question with the actual error you get ? error snippet

Comment: This is the error I am getting on webpage

Comment: Can you put the stack strace. looking at the error, look like above view is not being called, otherwise your code `customer=request.customer.user` would have  been `customer=request.user.customer`

Comment: Customer model has a foreign key user. Also customer=request.user.customer is working for every other function in views.py except this one

Comment: It was request.user.customer only..I did typo here...Still the erro is same

Answer (score 0):

It means the user you are trying to use in accessing the page at that time is not logged in. also `customer=request.customer.user` should be `customer=request.user.customer`.

You could check the user whom is requesting this page is authenticated or not with:

```py
if request.user.is_authenticated():
  # Your code here
```

something like:

```
@csrf_exempt
def handlerequest(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        customer=request.user.customer
        order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        form = request.POST
        response_dict = {}
        for i in form.keys():
            response_dict[i] = form[i]
            if i == 'CHECKSUMHASH':
                checksum = form[i]
    
            verify = Checksum.verify_checksum(response_dict, MERCHANT_KEY, checksum)
            if verify:
                if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
                    
                    print('order successful')
            else:
                print('order was not successful because' + response_dict['RESPMSG'])
        return render(request, 'paymentstatus.html', {'response':response_dict,'types':Category.objects.all()})
```

Comment: Yes it is request.user.customer only but it is not working. I am getting the same error.Even in HTML of the page rendered by that particular view when I use if request.user.is_authenticated it doesnt show me logged in even when the person is logged in. Also in other HTML pages of my site it is working fine but only in this page it is not.

Comment: In your template you can check if a user is authenticated by using `user.is_authenticated` like `{% if user.is_authenticated %} #show something {% endif %}`

Comment: In your view before anything try to print the output of `request.user`

Comment: I did it in my template as in the nav bar i wanted to show if the user is logged in or not and apparently no user was logged . But in all other templates it was showing logged in which is the case actually

Comment: Have you updated your view to be like what I did above?

Comment: if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer=request.user.customer
        order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        print(request.user)
    else:
        print("not logged in")                           i tried this and its printing not logged in but user is logged in as when I go to login page it shows me already logged in and on other pages in template too it shows logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this issue, because that user has not logged in yet. Django treat them as `AnonymousUser` and AnonymousUser does not have the `customer` attribute.

If the view is only for logged in user, you can add the login_required decorator to the view function to force the login process. Otherwise, you can check anonymous user with the is_authenticated condition.

[Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users) for reference

Comment: Thats my problem exactly. Even when the user is logged in It is showing this.